# how to connect 2 tables in php without common relation

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables
From table 1(student): I want `id, name, and roll_no`
From table 2(score): I want `SUM(`total`), SUM(`score`)` with some condition

And I want all student same class data from `student` table combine with `score` table to get each student SUM(`total`) and SUM(`score`) of some condition in `student` table.

In `score` table I have `student_id` name column and in `student`

I have `id` column which can be linked to each other if possible...

How can I achieve this??

I want this all-in-1 query to get the data in ascending order by `score` column...

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Learn SQL :-/

Comment: Please provide your table structure as `CREATE` and `INSERT` queries and provide sample data that you want to acquire. Also include what you have tried so far.